# Indy 10 Multipart upload to OneDrive Error

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, onedrive

I am trying to do [Multipart upload to OneDrive using POST](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_post.htm) and get 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'. IdLogFile:

```
Stat Connected.
Sent 10.02.2017 12:50:08: POST /v1.0/drive/root::/children HTTP/1.0`<EOL>`Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="Boundary"`<EOL>`Content-Length: 254`<EOL>`Authorization: Bearer EwA...%3d`<EOL>`Host: api.onedrive.com`<EOL>`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`<EOL>`Accept-Encoding: identity`<EOL>`User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)`<EOL><EOL>`
Sent 10.02.2017 12:50:08: --Boundary`<EOL>`Content-ID: <metadata>`<EOL>`Content-Type: application/json`<EOL>`{"name":"Dest.txt", "file":{}, "@content.sourceUrl":"cid:content"}`<EOL>`--Boundary`<EOL>`Content-ID: <content><EOL>Content-Type: application/octet-stream<SourceContent>--Boundary--
Recv 10.02.2017 12:50:08: H
Recv 10.02.2017 12:50:08: TTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`<EOL>`Via: 1.1 DM5SCH102210409 (wls-colorado)`<EOL>`Content-Length: 60`<EOL>`Content-Type: application/json`<EOL>`Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5`<EOL>`P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"`<EOL>`X-WLSPROXY: DM5SCH102210409`<EOL>`X-MSNSERVER: DM5SCH102231823`<EOL>`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains`<EOL>`X-QosStats: {"ApiId":0,"ResultType":2,"SourcePropertyId":0,"TargetPropertyId":42}`<EOL>`X-ThrowSite: 1479.b891`<EOL>`X-AsmVersion: UNKNOWN; 16.0.0.0`<EOL>`X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: A9918FA26FAF469EB3797E9DAEA3172E Ref B: FRAEDGE0409 Ref C: Fri Feb 10 01:50:09 2017 PST`<EOL>`Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 09:50:09 GMT`<EOL>`Connection: close`<EOL><EOL>`{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Bad Argument"}}
Stat Disconnected.
```

The code:

```
procedure TSaveFilter.UploadTest;
const
  URL = 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root::/children';
  Boundary = 'Boundary';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  MemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
  FileStream: TFileStream;

  procedure WriteLnString(str: AnsiString; CRLF: Boolean = True);
  begin
    if CRLF then str := str + #13#10;
    MemoryStream.Write(str[1], Length(str));
  end;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + FAccessToken;
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := Format('multipart/related; boundary="%s"', [Boundary]);

    MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      WriteLnString('--' + Boundary);
      WriteLnString('Content-ID: <metadata>');
      WriteLnString('Content-Type: application/json');
      WriteLnString('{"name":"Dest.txt", "file":{}, "@content.sourceUrl":"cid:content"}');
      WriteLnString('--' + Boundary);
      WriteLnString('Content-ID: <content>');
      WriteLnString('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', False);
      FileStream := TFileStream.Create('Source.txt', fmOpenRead);
      try
        MemoryStream.CopyFrom(FileStream, FileStream.Size);
      finally
        FileStream.Free;
      end;
      WriteLnString('--' + Boundary + '--', False);
      IdHTTP.Post(URL, MemoryStream);
    finally
      MemoryStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is a working request (List children):

```
Stat Connected.
Sent 10.02.2017 20:52:42: GET /v1.0/drive/root::/children?select=name,folder,file HTTP/1.1`<EOL>`Authorization: Bearer EwA...%3d`<EOL>`Host: api.onedrive.com`<EOL>`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`<EOL>`Accept-Encoding: identity`<EOL>`User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)`<EOL>``<EOL>`
Recv 10.02.2017 20:52:43: H
Recv 10.02.2017 20:52:43: TTP/1.1 200 OK`<EOL>`Via: 1.1 BN2BAP4ED8CB55D (wls-colorado)`<EOL>`Content-Length: 213`<EOL>`Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal`<EOL>`Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5`<EOL>`P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"`<EOL>`X-WLSPROXY: BN2BAP4ED8CB55D``X-MSNSERVER: DM5SCH102231619`<EOL>`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains`<EOL>`OData-Version: 4.0`<EOL>`X-AsmVersion: UNKNOWN; 16.0.0.0`<EOL>`X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: ECB06A4BE05B478AB36611C892C36CC7 Ref B: AM1EDGE0419 Ref C: Fri Feb 10 09:52:43 2017 PST``Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 17:52:43 GMT`<EOL>``<EOL>`{"@odata.context":"https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('me')/items('root')/children(name,folder,file)","value":[{"name":"AB","folder":{"childCount":7}},{"name":"ArecaBackup","folder":{"childCount":6}}]}
Stat Disconnected.
```

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler2 to capture a working request, and compare it with the Delphi request?

Comment: @mjn I use IdLogFile (Indy). It capture working request.

Comment: Please show the working HTTP request too

Comment: @mjn A working request is too big for comment - added in the question.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I wanted to suggest: use a different client, such as a C# or Java version. Execute the same request with it, and capture its HTTP traffic. Then you can compare that working request with the same HTTP traffic of the Delphi client.

Comment: @mjn Thanks, now it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MIME data is malformed, that is why the server is rejecting it.

This is the request you are sending:

```
POST /v1.0/drive/root::/children HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="Boundary"
Content-Length: 254
Authorization: Bearer EwA...%3d
Host: api.onedrive.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

--Boundary
Content-ID: <metadata>
Content-Type: application/json
{"name":"Dest.txt", "file":{}, "@content.sourceUrl":"cid:content"}
--Boundary
Content-ID: <content>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream<SourceContent>--Boundary--
```

As you can see, the MIME data is all messed up.  Specifically, each MIME field is missing some required `CRLF`s.  Just like with the HTTP headers and body, MIME headers and body are separated by a `<CRLF><CRLF>` sequence, and there needs to be a `CRLF` between the `TFileStream` data and the MIME boundary that follows it.

The request needs to look more like this instead:

```
POST /v1.0/drive/root::/children HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="Boundary"
Content-Length: 260
Authorization: Bearer EwA...%3d
Host: api.onedrive.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

--Boundary
Content-ID: <metadata>
Content-Type: application/json

{"name":"Dest.txt", "file":{}, "@content.sourceUrl":"cid:content"}
--Boundary
Content-ID: <content>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<SourceContent>
--Boundary--
```

Try this code to populate the `TMemoryStream`:

```
MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  WriteLnString('--' + Boundary);
  WriteLnString('Content-ID: <metadata>');
  WriteLnString('Content-Type: application/json');
  WriteLnString(''); // <-- ADD THIS!!!
  WriteLnString('{"name":"Dest.txt", "file":{}, "@content.sourceUrl":"cid:content"}');
  WriteLnString('--' + Boundary);
  WriteLnString('Content-ID: <content>');
  WriteLnString('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); // <-- REMOVE THE FALSE!!!
  WriteLnString(''); // <-- ADD THIS!!!

  FileStream := TFileStream.Create('Source.txt', fmOpenRead);
  try
    MemoryStream.CopyFrom(FileStream, 0);
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;

  WriteLnString(''); // <!-- ADD THIS!!!
  WriteLnString('--' + Boundary + '--', False);
  ...
finally
  MemoryStream.Free;
end;
```

That being said, Indy has a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` class that is typically used with `TIdHTTP` when sending `multipart/form-data` posts.  OneDrive does not support `multipart/form-data`, but what is odd is that OneDrive's documentation clearly specifies the following, which only applies to `multipart/form-data` and not to `multipart/related`:

> The request will be rejected if more than two parts are included. **Each part must specify a `name` value in the `Content-Disposition` header that indicates which part it is**. Parts can be in either order, but should specify the metadata part first.

However, the example given in the same documentation is using `multipart/related`, just like your code is.  There are discussions in Microsoft/OneDrive forums and various blogs regarding whether to use `multipart/form-data` or `multipart/related` when uploading to OneDrive.  One OneDrive employee did confirm this issue needs some work on their end.

Just in case OneDrive ever supports `multipart/form-data`, here is a example using `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`:

```
procedure TSaveFilter.UploadTest;
const
  URL = 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root::/children';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  PostData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + FAccessToken;

    PostData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      PostData.AddFormField('metadata', '{"name":"Dest.txt", "file":{}}', 'utf-8', 'application/json');
      PostData.AddFile('content', 'Source.txt', 'application/octet-stream').FileName := '';
      IdHTTP.Post(URL, PostData);
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, @RemyLebeau.
`Content-Type: multipart/related;` works OK with Indy 10, but it causes '501 The requested feature isn’t implemented' with Indy 9. Sent file, at the same time, saved OK. I think I will ignore the Exception.
`TIdMultipartFormDataStream` still does not work for now.