# Indy 10 + XE8 multipart upload with long filename

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-2009, box, indy10

I am trying to do [multipart upload to Box.com](https://docs.box.com/v2.0/reference#upload-a-file) using TIdMultipartFormDataStream. While file name is up to  '\u0424\u042B\u0412\u0410\u041F.txt' it works OK, but when it longer ('\u0424\u042B\u0412\u0410\u041F\u0420.txt') it causes 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'.

Is there some limitation for FormField.FFieldValue length? If so, is there any way to bypass it?

```
procedure TBoxComSaveFilter.UploadTest;
const
  URL = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  MD: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + FAccessToken;
    MD := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      MD.AddFormField('metadata', '{"name": "' +
        '\u0424\u042B\u0412\u0410\u041F.txt' +       // => OK
//        '\u0424\u042B\u0412\u0410\u041F\u0420.txt' + // => 400 Bad Request
        '", "parent": {"id": "0"}}', '', 'application/json');

      MD.AddFile('content', 'source.txt', 'application/octet-stream');
      IdHTTP.Post(URL, MD);
    finally
      MD.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

A partial log for short filename:

```
Sent 20.02.2017 21:16:26: ----------022017211625520
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

{"name": "\u0424\u042B\u0412\u0410\u041F.txt", "parent": {"id": "0"}}
----------022017211625520
```

The same part for long filename:

```
Sent 20.02.2017 21:17:48: ----------022017211748412
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

{"name": "\u0424\u042B\u0412\u0410\u041F\u0420.txt", "parent": {"id": =
"0"}}
----------022017211748412
```

As I can see the data split after 70 byte by "=CRLF".

Comment: There is no limit in `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` itself, but there is on Box's end: "*Box only supports file names of 255 characters or less. Names that will not be supported are those that contain non-printable ascii, / or \, names with trailing spaces, and the special names “.” and “..”.*"

Comment: Why are you JSON-encoding the Unicode characters, though? You should not need to do that: `MD.AddFormField('metadata', '{"name": "ФЫВАПР.txt", "parent": {"id": "0"}}', 'utf-8', 'application/json');`

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. I tried "ФЫВАПР.txt" and 'utf-8' and the result was 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'. The log: `{"name": "=D0=A4=D0=AB=D0=92=D0=90=D0=9F=D0=A0.txt", "parent": {"id": =CRLF`
`"0"}}`

Comment: I am sorry that I skiped logs at first. With the logs it seems to me that Indy split data by '=CRLF'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default transfer encoding for text fields is MIME's `quoted-printable` format. It would seem Box does not like that format.

`AddFormField()` returns a `TIdFormDataField`, which has a `ContentTransfer` property you can set it to `8bit` or `binary` to send the JSON text as-is (after it is charset encoded to bytes, that is):

```
MD.AddFormField('metadata', '{"name": "ФЫВАПР.txt", "parent": {"id": "0"}}', 'utf-8', 'application/json').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
```

Alternatively, put your JSON in a `TStream`, like `TStringStream` or `TMemoryStream`, and then use the `TStream` overload of `AddFormField()`, which sets the `ContentTransfer` to `binary` by default:

```
JsonStream := TStringStream.Create('{"name": "ФЫВАПР.txt", "parent": {"id": "0"}}', TEncoding.UTF8);
try
  MD.AddFormField('metadata', 'application/json', 'utf-8', JsonStream);
  // send the post...
finally
  JsonStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Both of your methods works OK. Also I tried TMemoryStream like [multipart upload to OneDrive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157101/indy-10-multipart-upload-to-onedrive-error): it works too. Thanks @RemyLebeau.